# What is the name of this anime i watched in 2004?

Tags: brave-police-j-decker

I do not know whether is is an anime or cartoon because the channel i watched on only shows dubbed cartoons.
Here are the details

- Its a robot-based show
- The only robots i could remember are three of them - One was a police themed robot , Another one is an ambulance themed robot and the last one i could remember is a firetruck themed robot.
- Each robot is made up of 1 main robot and 4 smaller ones( all of which could turn into vehicles ( police car , ambulance and firetruck respectively))
- these 5 robots would combine into one awesome , cool-looking robots. The main bot will be the torso and the head while the 4 smaller ones would be the limbs.
- All the robots are piloted by kids and together(with the help of the robots) , they became are the firefighters , policeman and the paramedics of the country

These are all the details that lingered in my mind. Sorry for the limited information . Please help me:(

Please note that it is NOT transformers. The robots are controlled by (about) 10 years old paramedics , policeman and firefighters.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Sounds like [Brave Police J-Decker](http://gaogaigar.wikia.com/wiki/Brave_Police_J-Decker). Here's a summary from the wiki:

> Brave Police J-Decker was the fifth anime of the Brave Series and aired in Japan during 1994 and 1995.
>
> Brave Police J-Decker returns the series to a subtly lighter tone, focusing more on the concept of "robot as human-built AI construct" emphasized by the previous season's series, Brave Express Might Gaine. Grade schooler Yuuta Tominaga stumbles upon Deckerd, a humanoid robot under construction by the Japanese police, built to fight advanced forms of crime. Yuuta's constant contact with Deckerd gives the robot a "heart", or personality; when Yuuta is recruited as the "boss" of the "Brave Police" as a result, a true human/robot partnership occurs.

It's got mechas that are Police, Firetruck, and Ambulance themed.

- **Deckerd:** The sentient police robot that transforms into a police cruiser.
- **Duke:** A sentient robot that transforms into an ambulance.
- **Fire Roader:** A massive firetruck that serves as Duke's support vehicle.

They combine in various combinations as well as the "**Fire J-Decker Max Cannon Mode**", a combination of all the vehicles.

Comment: This picture looks like Jubilee with the Gundams. :P